# Error sending snmptrap from zabbix to an APC

Tags: zabbix, apc

I have a problem sending a snmptrap via zabbix to an APC, so that it automatically generates alerts about the status of the APC, at the moment I can only do this manually, whether via zabbix or by monitoring the APC, I would like I wonder if anyone knows a way to do this to make it automatic?

I've already tried configuring all of Zabbix to make it automatic, but I didn't get any results.

Comment: English only please. Otherwise use https://es.stackoverflow.com/.